# How to map a list of strings and list of integers and find the string that has greatest value

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, int

I have been troubles by this. I have two lists

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
listb = [80, 90, 70, 60]
```

I want to map it so 
"a" has a value of 80
"b" has a value of 90
"c" has a value of 70 and
"d" has a value of 60
Then, I want to print the string that has the largest value and the second largest value.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You asked for the largest and the second largest value but you accepted an answer that gives you _only_ the largest value.   If this is your intention, maximum respect.  Otherwise, there are answers that address _exactly_ your question.

Comment: @gboffi, The confusion for my answer arose (partly) because of the very specific question in the title. I have updated (via `heapq`) to address top *n* answers (similar to yours but using `itemgetter`).

Comment: @jpp My answer is now useless → remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `max` for highest value only

For your result, you don't *need* an explicit mapping, e.g. via a dictionary. You can calculate the *index* of the highest value and then apply this to your key list:

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
listb = [80, 90, 70, 60]

# a couple of alternatives to extract index with maximum value
idx = max(range(len(listb)), key=lambda x: listb[x])  # 1
idx, _ = max(enumerate(listb), key=lambda x: x[1])    # 1

maxkey = lista[idx]  # 'b'
```

#### `heapq` for highest *n* values

If you want to the highest *n* values, a full sort is not necessary. You can use `heapq.nlargest`:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

n = 2

# a couple of alternatives to extract index with n highest values
idx = nlargest(n, range(len(listb)), key=lambda x: listb[x])      # [1, 0]
idx, _ = zip(*nlargest(n, enumerate(listb), key=lambda x: x[1]))  # (1, 0)

maxkeys = itemgetter(*idx)(lista)  # ('b', 'a')
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know what is enumerate and how to use lambda. It ran perfectly.

Comment: @Ragent, See [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
print(lista[listb.index(max(listb))])
```

It finds the maximum numbers index of `listb`, then gets the item of that same index in `lista`.

This should work, however I recommend using python dicts in the future for this kind of thing.

Comment: To note, you're iterating `listb` twice in this solution, which isn't strictly necessary. You can extract the index while you look for the `max` via a single iteration, e.g. via `range` or `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [80, 90, 70, 60]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dictionary)
{'a': 80, 'b': 90, 'c': 70, 'd': 60}
```

I guess you could try using operator.itemgetter:

```
import operator
max(dictionary.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Tell me if this worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [80, 90, 70, 60]
print keys[values.index(max(values))]
```

Comment: A full sort is will be inefficient here, especially for large inputs.

Comment: you are correct, after thinking it through I changed my answer to a more efficient solution

Comment: which is exactly the same solution as @Qwerty proposed (I didn't see ir before editing my answer, sorry)