# How to map a list of strings and list of integers and print the string that has the second greatest value

Tags: python, list, sorting, int

I have been troubles by this. I have two lists

> lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>
> listb = [80, 90, 70, 60]

I want to map it so

"a" has a value of 80

"b" has a value of 90

"c" has a value of 70 and

"d" has a value of 60

Then, I want to print the string that has the second largest value, which is "a"

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did we just do one of your homework assignments?

Answer (score 0):

To determine the second highest value, you need to track, at a minimum, the *top two values* in your iterable. So use `heapq` again, similar to [your previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306005/how-to-map-a-list-of-strings-and-list-of-integers-and-find-the-string-that-has-g).

```
from heapq import nlargest

lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
listb = [80, 90, 70, 60]

n = 2
idx, _ = zip(*nlargest(n, enumerate(listb), key=lambda x: x[1]))  # (1, 0)
key = lista[idx[-1]]                                              # 'a'
```

Only for large values of *n* should you consider a full sort, where [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) may perform better.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `argsort`'ing `listb` which returns the indices of the sorted items. Then select from `lista` with the second highest index. `argsort` is available in `numpy`.

```
import numpy

second_largest_str = lista[numpy.argsort(listb)[-2]]
print(second_largest_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of approaching this is to create a dictionary where the list of characters is the **Key** and the list of integers are the **Values**

There are probably a ton of ways of doing this, this is just one!

Zip takes two lists and creates a dictionary out of them, the first argument being the Key, and the second argument being the value

```
a = ["A", "B", "C"]
b = [1, 2, 3]
dict_1 = dict(zip(a,b))
print(dict_1)
>>> {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Then you could use this to sort the dictionary by value from smallest to largest

```
x = sorted((k,v) for v,k in dict_1.items())
```

Then to access the second to largest you could access the dictionary from the right hand side (Negative Indexing)

```
print(x[-2])
>>> (3, 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd

In [2210]: lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

In [2211]: listb = [80, 90, 70, 60]

In [2213]: df = pd.DataFrame(lista)

In [2214]: df['listb'] = listb

In [2215]: df
Out[2215]: 
   0  listb
0  a     80
1  b     90
2  c     70
3  d     60
```

Then find the 2nd highest like below:

```
In [2228]: df.nlargest(2, 'listb').tail(1).values.tolist()
Out[2228]: [['a', 80]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple enough version for the same

```
d = {}
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
j = [80, 90, 70, 60]

for i in range(len(l)):
    d[str(l[i])] = j[i]

d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(d[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The sorted() function takes an optional key argument:

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 
listb = [80, 90, 70, 60] 

pairs = zip(lista, listb)
sorted_tuples = sorted(pairs, key=(lambda pair : pair[1]), reverse=True)
str_with_second_highest_nr = sorted_tuples[1][0]
```

You could zip it together to a pairs of lista and listb and sort these after the second item in each tuple with a lambda function as key argument.
Then just pick first position of the second pair

```
>>> print(sorted_tuples)
[('b', 90), ('a', 80), ('c', 70), ('d', 60)]

>>> print(str_with_second_highest_nr)
a
```